Macbook Pro / Intel chip, running WIndows 10 natevly. To log in I need to press ctl-alt-del. External kbd works. How to do that from the laptop kbd?
I have a Macbook Pro A1398. I formatted the hard drive to run Windows 10 without any virtual OS. It does not have MAC OS asny longer. Everything works perfectly, even joined to corporate domain. The only thing that I still have issues with is I can't log in without a external keyboard. Currently I have the registry set to auto-login, but I'd like to be able to press ctl-alt-del without the keyboard attached. I've read all the threads I could find, but nothing works. I keep seeing ctl-option-escape and other methods. Is there a patch I need to load?

Your desire to press "CTRL+A:T+DEL" without a keyboard is confusing. How do you use the machine without a keyboard?
